# Number of voting in one-vs-one strategy in multi-class classification

Tags: android, opencv, svm, libsvm

I am using OpenCV library in android for image classification. To classify images I am using a SVM classifier. I want to suggest many classes to user as a result. First class is best choice and second is next choice and so on. I know that Libsvm has probability prediction and can do this work, But OpenCV uses an old version of Libsvm and that version does not have probability prediction.

Libsvm uses one-vs-one strategy for multi-class classification. In one-vs-one strategy, Libsvm uses voting between every two possible class. Then the winner is the result of prediction. How we can know the number of voting that other classes have for sorting classes? Means that I want to use the number of voting for sorting classes. Is this strategy good for sorting classes?

Comment: why not use libSVM directly?

Comment: @stefan Because I want to use OpenCv’s LibSVM. I know that I can compile LibSVM and use in Android, but it is difficult.